# Postman Examples Dynamic Response Based on Request Data

Tags: postman, postman-mocks

Probably missing something completely obvious in the docs but is it possible to echo request data in a Postman Example / Mock Server response based on the input request.

Example Request:

POST:

```
{
    "firstName": "{{$randomFirstName}}",
    "lastName": "{{$randomLastName}}",
    "phoneNumber": "{{$randomPhoneNumber}}",
    "email": "{{$randomExampleEmail}}",
    "employeeId": "{{$randomInt}}"
}
```

Intended example response:

```
{
    "id": {{$randomInt}},
    "firstName": "{{$req.firstName}}",
    "lastName": "{{$req.lastName}}",
    "phoneNumber": "{{$req.phoneNumber}}",
    "email": "{{$req.email}}",
    "employeeId": "{{$req.employeeId}}"
}
```

Comment: did you try http://postman-echo.com/post

Comment: you can associate only environment variable in mock , so it will return the value of that particular environment variable . Its not dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to use Postman's dynamic 'faker' variables in the request body to be returned in the mock response. A similar use case is supported for the request URL (refer to the section on 'wildcards' [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/matching-algorithm/)) but not body.

Here's one way to achieve this with the request body:

1. Create an environment 'e1' with variable 'firstName'.
2. Edit your mock to add the environment 'e1'.
3. Use the same environment variable `{{firstName}}` in the response body of your example.
4. Dynamically update the value of 'firstName' before sending the mock request. If you're using the Postman client, you can do this using the `pm.environment.set` [method](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-environment-variables-in-scripts). If not, then you can use the [Postman API](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-public-workspace/request/12959542-ece4c556-18ee-4baa-ac05-9c492caf6a97) to do this.

On the other hand, you can simply use the same faker variable `{{$randomFirstVariable}}` in your mock example response as well, but the value returned could differ from the one sent in the request.